# Laravel ajax request

Tags: ajax, laravel, сеть

Здравствуйте есть такой проблем не могу просмотрет филди запроса через айакс на нетворку
только на одном проекте так
за акцент извините
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не могу открит array не дает возможност кому то било такой проблема?

Comment: Вкладка headers внизу смотрите свои поля. То что на скрине - ответ сервера, где, больше всего, стоит какой-то dd

Comment: Да я написал dd хочу просмотреть что внутри array но не откривает

Comment: Там пустой массив, судя по Вашему скрину

Comment: Неа туту не пустой массив дело в том что не могу открит массив не дает возможност, а на другом проекте можно открит

Comment: если сделаю dd($data->categories); то показает внутр массива